# Weird redirect when authenticating and api_key through devise on rails3 with rspec and rack/test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rack

I'm using rack/test and rspec on Rails 3 to authenticate a users api key through devise. Any request I make returns a status of 302 and a response of: "You are being redirected.". Can't seem to figure out how to authenticate.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Api::V1::CollectController do
  def app
    Rails.application
  end 

  context 'user' do
    subject do
      FactoryGirl.create :user
    end

    it 'allow valid api credentials' do
      post '/api/collect', {}, { 'Authentication' => subject.authentication_token }
      p last_response.body
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a working solution. But I'm not satisfied with why the original approach didn't work. I eliminated rack/test and changed the way I interface with the controller. The following worked. I'm mostly just curious now...

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Api::V1::CollectController do
  context 'user' do
    subject do
      FactoryGirl.create :user
    end

    it 'allow valid api credentials' do
      post :create, {}, { 'Authentication' => subject.authentication_token }
      p response.body
    end
  end
end
```